# Reference from type table to symbol table

Tags: compiler-construction, symbol-tables

We all know that there is always a reference from symbol table to type table but recerse case can also happen. Means can type table reference back to symbol table? If yes, please provide example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a new type you usually give it a name, so this name, as a symbol, will be referenced from the type table.

Comment: define a new type means? Say if I define a struture and give it a name X then what it means in context to your statement. N thanks for your reply

Comment: If you define a new structure X then that means you define a new type X. A new entry is added to symbol table ('X') and to type table as well (a compiler's structure describing your new type's definition).